ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID playwright
I am using playwright in a Docker container that runs in AWS Batch env.
I am able to successfully test from VS Code but it errors out as ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when it runs from a container.
These are my relevant pieces of code.
test.ts
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import type { User } from './types';

const defaultPassword = 'xxxx';

export const test = base.extend<{ user: User }>({
  user: { username: '' },
  storageState: async ({ browser, user, baseURL }, use, testInfo) => {
    if (!user.username) {
      return;
    }
    const fileName = path.join(
      testInfo.project.outputDir,
      `storage-${user.username}-${testInfo.workerIndex}.json`
    );

    if (!fs.existsSync(fileName)) {
      const page = await browser.newPage({ storageState: undefined });
      await page.goto(baseURL ?? '/select-client');
      await page.click('role=button[name="AGREE & CONTINUE"]');
      await page.fill('#userName', user.username);
      await page.fill('#password', user.password ?? defaultPassword);
      await page.click('role=button[name="LOGIN"]');
      await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
      await page.context().storageState({ path: fileName });
    }
    console.log("Base URL:", baseURL);
    await use(fileName);
  },
});
export { expect } from '@playwright/test';

playwright.config.js
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  //testDir: path.join(__dirname, 'playwright', 'tests'),
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 1 : 0,

  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : 1,
  reporter: [
    ['html', { open: 'never' }],
    ['line'],
    // ["allure-playwright", { outputFolder: "reports/allure" }],
    ['junit', { outputFile: 'reports/results.xml' }],
    ['json', { outputFile: 'reports/results.json' }],
  ],
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
    /* Maximum time each action such as `click()` can take. Defaults to 0 (no limit). */
    actionTimeout: 0,
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
    baseURL: 'https://my-url.com',
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
    headless: true,
    storageState: 'storage.json',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    },
  ],
});

test case spec file:
import { Page, Locator, chromium } from '@playwright/test';
import { TransactionTypesPage } from '../../pages/transactionTypes.js';
import { CommonActions } from '../../pages/commonMethods';
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login';
import { test, expect } from '../../module/test';
import { imUser } from '../../module/users';
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

const today = new Date();
const todayDtTime = today.toISOString().replace(/[:T.]/g, '-').slice(0, -5);

let txnDetails = new TransactionTypeDetails();

test.describe('Transaction Types Test Set', () => {
  console.log('Current working directory in test:', process.cwd());

  test.use({ user: imUser, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });

  let page;
  let transTypePage;
  let commonActions;
  let loginPage;

  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser, baseURL }) => {
    //const context = await browser.newContext({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.route(() => true, (route) => {
      route.fulfill( { status: 403, })
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    transTypePage = new TransactionTypesPage(page);
    commonActions = new CommonActions(page);
    loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
    await page.goto('/select-client', { timeout: 6000, waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle');
    console.log("Base URL----> ", page.url());
    await loginPage.loginForStaticDataClient();
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
    await commonActions.clickAdminLink();
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
    await transTypePage.clickTransactionTypesLink();
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  });

test('Click ADD NEW button', async () => {
await commonActions.clickAddNewButton();
await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
});

test('Enter Name', async() => {
  await transTypePage.enterName("PW-Test-Name-" + todayDtTime);
  txnDetails.name = "PW-Test-Name-" + todayDtTime
});

test('More tests...')

I also have the Dockerfile with this content:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:latest
ENV CI=true
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates \
        && update-ca-certificates
# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/csg-treasury-web-ui-app

# Install dependencies for AWS CLI installation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install AWS CLI v2
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
&& unzip awscliv2.zip \
&& ./aws/install \
&& rm awscliv2.zip \
&& rm -rf aws

RUN echo "AWS CLI installation successful"

# Install Playwright browsers
RUN npx playwright install chromium
RUN echo "Playwright and Chromium installation successful"

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of your project files
COPY . .

RUN pwd
RUN ls -lt

# Install Playwright browsers
RUN npx playwright install

RUN echo playwright install successful
RUN pwd
RUN chmod +x ./run.sh

RUN echo "Playwright version is:"
RUN npx playwright --version

# Change the working directory to the playwright folder
RUN echo "Change dir to playwright in the container..."
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/csg-treasury-web-ui-app/playwright
RUN pwd
RUN ls -lt

CMD ["bash", "/usr/src/app/csg-treasury-web-ui-app/run.sh"]

The run.sh starts the playwright test like this.
npx playwright test ./tests/TransactionType/ --workers 1 --reporter=list,html

What I see is this error from AWS logs.
Error: page.goto: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID at https://my-url.com
Its trying to lauch the URL but then fails with this error.
As you can see I have --ignoreHTTPSErrors in my playwright.config file and also in my test file, but still no luck. I am not sure if I am missing anything here.
I also have "scripts": {"test": "playwright test --ignore-https-errors"} in my package.json.
Any help to solve this much appreciated.

I had a similar situation in which I kept getting the same error as you. I tried all of the same solutions. The only thing that worked was adding launchOptions: { args: ["--ignore-certificate-errors"] } to the individual browser objects. The suggestions in the Playwright docs didn't seem to help.
Full example with Chromium:
// playwright.config.ts

/* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Chrome"],
        launchOptions: {
          args: ["--ignore-certificate-errors"],
        },
      },
    },
  ],

